# Why the value coming from a get request isn't accessable in the blade file?

Tags: laravel, global-variables

I have the following controller method, where I would like to make the $clientId able to be accessed in `mails.projectRequest` blade file.

I tried to do that through the `ProjectRequestMail`class but it does not work. Is there something wrong or this is not the way to do that?

My **controller method**:

```
public function sendProjectTeam($projectClientId) {

            $projectClientEmail = Client::where('id', $projectClientId)->value('email');

            Mail::to($projectClientEmail)->send(new ProjectRequestMail($projectClientId));

            return ['success' => true, 'message' => 'Email was sent'];
        }
```

**ProjectRequestMail** class:

```
class ProjectRequestMail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
 * @var
 */
public $projectClientId;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @param $user
 */
public function __construct($projectClientId)
{
    //
    $this->project_client_id = $projectClientId;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */

public function build()
{
    $this->from('hello@signifly.com');

    $this->subject('New Project Request from Signifly');

    return $this->markdown('mails.projectRequest');
}
}
```

and finally **ProjectRequest blade**

```
@component('mail::message')
Hello,

You have received a new request regarding your project.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => env('APP_URL'). '/#/project-requests/' . $projectClientId ])
See request
@endcomponent


Best regards,<br>
The ... team
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Try using $this->markdown(‘mails.projectRequest’)->with(‘projectClientId’, $this->project_client_id)

Comment: it did not work.

Comment: if I dd($projectClientId) inside the ProjectRequestMail class is "1" inside build() is undefined and inside the blade file is null. How is that possible?

Comment: Based on your code snippet above, the class variable is declared dynamically in the construct. Your class variable is declared as $projectClientId, but inside the construct you are accessing $this->project_client_id ? Why so. You should do $this->projectClientId = $projectClientId in the construct. This is generic programming practice. And what is that you are exactly doing dd on ?

Comment: I was doing dd at $projectClientId. But that was the mistake, thank's a lot. As I am new to programming I did not know about this naming convention does make a difference.